# Type error: Argument 1 passed to Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::__construct() must be an instance of Jenssegers\Mongodb\Connection

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

An application which is written in Laravel using mondodb as backend where "jenssegers/laravel-mongodb" vendor used as interface. Post loading application in browser throws following error :

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Jenssegers\Mongodb\Connection, instance of
>   Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution which helped me :**

In .env file which overrides the config files. 
it had `DB_CONNECTION=mysql.`

Changing it to following, fixed this bug.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
```

**Work of caution** :
Please ensure to provide correct value based on your server setup for following .env variable, I've kept it as default.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: I am down voting this because it fails to cover a case where both mysql and mongo are used.  This same answer is in 100 places and not one example of using both.

Comment: The `protected $connection = 'mongodb';` can be used to specify a mongodb model.

Comment: @AlexBarker This question is specific to setting MongoDB as the default DB connection What you mentioned is a different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

if using two database connection together and have this problem with passport
modify setting in this Path:

```
vendor/laravel/passport/config/passport.php
```

and then change this lines:

```
'storage' => [
    'database' => [
        'connection' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'yourdb'),
    ],
],
```